# Random number from many other random numbers, is it more random?

Tags: algorithm, random

We want to generate a uniform random number from the interval [0, 1].
Let's first generate k random booleans (for example by rand()<0.5) and decide according to these on what subinterval [m*2^{-k}, (m+1)*2^{-k}] the number will fall. Then we use one rand() to get the final output as m*2^{-k} + rand()*2^{-k}.
Let's assume we have arbitrary precision.

Will a random number generated this way be 'more random' than the usual rand()?

PS. I guess the subinterval picking amounts to just choosing the binary representation of the output 0. b_1 b_2 b_3... one digit b_i at a time and the final step is adding the representation of rand() to the end of the output.

Comment: The "usual" `rand()` is pretty uniformly random.  What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question. But in some situations we could need 'more random' random numbers. For example in card shuffling, 52! is s big and someone could use the properties of rand() to their advantage (only a small fraction of the possible shuffles can be generated).

Comment: The usual way to combine random sources is with xor, in that case no matter what you xor the out put will be no less random than the most random input and may be more random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the definition of "more random". If you use more random generators, it means more random state, and it means that cycle length will be greater. But cycle length is just one property of random generators. Cycle length of 2^64 usually OK for almost any purpose (the only exception I know is that if you need a lot of different, long sequences, like for some kind of simulation).

However, if you combine two bad random generators, they don't necessarily become better, you have to analyze it. But there are generators, which do work this way. For example, [KISS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007.pdf) is an example for this: it combines 3, not-too-good generators, and the result is a good generator.

For card shuffling, you'll need a cryptographic RNG. Even a very good, but not cryptographic RNG is inadequate for this purpose. For example, Mersenne Twister, which is a good RNG, is not suitable for secure card shuffling! It is because observing output numbers, it is possible to figure out its internal state, so shuffle result can be predicted.

Answer (score 2):

This can help, but only if you use a different pseudorandom generator for the first and last bits.  (It doesn't have to be a different pseudorandom algorithm, just a different seed.)

If you use the same generator, then you will still only be able to construct 2^n different shuffles, where n is the number of bits in the random generator's state.

If you have two generators, each with n bits of state, then you can produce up to a total of 2^(2n) different shuffles.

Answer (score 2):

Tinkering with a random number generator, as you are doing by using only one bit of random space and then calling iteratively, usually weakens its random properties. All RNGs fail some statistical tests for randomness, but you are more likely to get find that a noticeable cycle crops up if you start making many calls and combining them.